# Znode creation criterion and proper usage

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have just started exploring Zookeeper , and I am much confused by concept of Znode , the doubts I have :

- On what basis client creates znode to save data , i.e. is there any pattern to save data in znode, while creating which present znode should be the parent.
- Do all the znode are present on every Zookeeper Nodes(server).
- How znode and Zookeeper server nodes are mapped?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for any web UI for zookeeper ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I regularly use command line tool `zkCli` (comes with a ZooKeeper installation) and it fulfilled my needs so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q:** On what basis client creates znode to save data , i.e. is there any
>   pattern to save data in znode, while creating which present znode
>   should be the parent?

It depends on the client's needs. One useful use-case is to check for a group membership: let's imagine that you have a group of servers that need to divide a fixed set of tasks among them. For example, there are 10 tasks, so if 3 servers are alive first will get 4 tasks and other two will get 3 tasks. Create a znode `/live-servers`, and instruct your servers to create child [ephemeral](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperOver.html#Nodes+and+ephemeral+nodes) znodes in this znode. By doing this, they will indicate that they are alive (so that they can get their portion of tasks to execute). As a result, ZooKeeper will have znodes `/live-servers/server-1`, `/live-servers/server-2`, `/live-servers/server-3` etc. Each of these znodes can store some useful data, such as an IP address of the server that created child znode. Your application can now iterate through the list of these znodes, find the IP addresses of live servers and send them tasks.

If a concept of znode keeps confusing you, compare it with a traditional filesystem, with one important difference: each file (znode) is in the same time a directory. Parent znode of all znodes is root znode, `/`, just like in traditional filesystems.

> **Q:** Do all the znode are present on every Zookeeper Nodes(server). How znode and Zookeeper server nodes are mapped?

Quoting from [ZooKeeper fundamentals, deployment, and applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-zookeeper/):

> The znode hierarchy is stored in memory **within each** of the ZooKeeper
>   servers.